# Database Merging Tables

Tags: mysql, database, merge

I just want to ask how to merge two tables.

Because I have a table guest and company both of them acquire a reservation.

I want to join both of them and label them as customers and I want to add a new column customer type which will say guest, if my company is null... and company, if my guest is null...

Here's an example:

```
guest(g_id(PK), name, guest details etc....)
company(c_id(PK), name, company details etc...)
reservation(r_id(PK), g_id(fk), c_id(fk), reservation details etc...)
```

When I join them (assuming guest has acquired a reservation) my table looks like

```
reservation_id|company name|guest name|reservation details
     1           null      <name>     <details>
     2           null      <name>     <details>
```

What I want is to make it like this:

```
reservation_id|customer name|cust_type|reservation details
     1          <name>      <guest>     <details>
     2          <name>      <company>     <details>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to first create a query for each type of reservation (which you might already have) and add the cust_type there, then union the two together. So the initial queries would be something like:

guest_reservations:

```
SELECT reservation.r_id, guest.name, "guest" AS cust_type, {other fields}
FROM guest, reservation INNER JOIN guest ON guest.g_id = reservation.g_id;
```

company_reservations:

```
SELECT reservation.r_id, company.name, "company" AS cust_type {other fields}
FROM company, reservation INNER JOIN company ON company.c_id = reservation.c_id;
```

Then you could union the two queries together, something like below.

```
SELECT reservation.r_id, guest.name, "guest" AS cust_type, {other fields}
FROM guest, reservation INNER JOIN guest ON guest.g_id = reservation.g_id
UNION SELECT reservation.r_id, company.name, "company" AS cust_type {other fields}
FROM company, reservation INNER JOIN company ON company.c_id = reservation.c_id;
```

Of course remember to either remove {other fields} or add in whatever else you need there.

Comment: +1 - and then create an insert statement that drops data into the new table, using this query as a data source

Comment: is this correct? ``SELECT *, "Guest" AS cust_type FROM guest JOIN reservation;``

Comment: You can't use the * and also have individual fields, you have to use one or the other. In this case you'll have to add the fields you want individually. So it would be something like `SELECT id, name, {other fields], "guest" as cust_type FROM guest JOIN reservation;`

Comment: ``UNION SELECT reservation_num, name, reservation_details FROM company_reservations`` why is there name in this query? what does that supposed to mean?

Comment: @nerdherd could you give a more simpler solution sir? based on my example given bcause I can't really understand what the person is trying to show me...

Comment: I was just giving an example of how you would write it. You'll have to stick in your real field names. If you aren't sure how to do that you might want to read up on SQL some more, for example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Comment: sir why is there ``FROM guest_reservations`` in your example. should I create a table for guest_reservations? I only have a reservation table sir. :))

Comment: I updated my answer to be a little more clear and follow your schema better. Does that clear anything up?

Comment: I've got the the guest and company reservation but the all_reservation, I don't understand why is there a ``FROM company_reservations`` and ``FROM guest_reservations`` I don't have any tables like that... :/

Comment: Thanks. I think you meant creating a view on your example? it already works fine now tahnks!! I created 2 views guest and client reservations and followed your query. :)))

Answer (score 2):

Not sure the schema is the best but consider the following tables:

Res (resId, description, cid, gid, details)

```
1   Guest Res   1   NULL    Just some guy
2   Comp Res    NULL    1   Corporate jerk
```

Guest (gid, name)

```
1   Chuck
```

Company (cid, name)

```
1   Tenth
```

Check out the parameters of the select query:

```
1. r.rid : id of reservation table
2. isnull(c.name, g.name) : gets the non null value from either company or guest
3. isnull(replace(c.name, c.name, 'Company'), 'Guest') as type
    Fanciness...if c.name is something, then 'Company', otherwise 'Guest'
4. r.details : reservation details
```

You need the outer join because of the nulls, this gives you a complete view of your data.

```
left outer join company c on r.cid = c.cid
left outer join guest g on r.gid = g.gid
```

So if you stick it all together you get what you are looking for:

```
select r.rid, r.description, isnull(c.name, g.name), 
isnull(replace(c.name, c.name, 'Company'), 'Guest') as type, 
r.details from res r
left outer join company c on r.cid = c.cid
left outer join guest g on r.gid = g.gid

1   Guest Res   Chuck   Guest   Just some guy
2   Comp Res    Tenth   Company Corporate jerk
```

Comment: sirhow can I get the companyname and guestname. I am only inserting ID in my reservation table;

Comment: ``select reservation_ID, isnull(guest_id, company_id) as name from reservation;`` why is this giving me an incorrect parameter count in the call to native function isnull.

Comment: I've already stated it here sir. its ``guest(guest_id, lastname, firstname, middlename)`` ``company(company_id, lastname, firstname, middlename)`` ``reservation(reservation_ID, guest_id(FK), company_id(FK)``

Comment: I just want to show the details which they are the same. (in my case lastname, firstname, middlename)

Comment: Ok, same concept just with 3 tables.  I'm going to delete my comments in a few minutes.