# How can I do a union/join in access to 'stack' 2 tables on top of each other while merging two columns

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables with rows that don't relate to each other except for 2 common fields. I'm trying to join them in such a way that there are 2 fields that merge.

For example:

Table A:

```
NameA    ID-A    SomefieldA    SomefieldB 
John     101     A-1           B-2
John     200     A-1           B-10
Smith    101     A-10          B-2
```

Table B:

```
NameB    ID-B    SomefieldC    SomefieldD
John     101     C-1           D-2
David    2000    C-100         A-10
George   120     C-2           D-20
```

I want to join these tables together so it would be like this:

Table C:

```
Name    ID    Somefield A    SomefieldB    SomefieldC    SomefieldD
John    101   A-1            B-2           (null)         (null)
John    200   A-1            B-10          (null)         (null)
Smith   101   A-10           B-2           (null)         (null)
John    101   (null)         (null)         C-1           D-2
David   2000  (null)         (null)         C-100         A-10
George  120   (null)         (null)         C-2           D-20
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database Merging Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406752/database-merging-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a simple union query. You will need to provide all fields in both tables.

```sql
SELECT NameA, [ID-A] As ID, SomefieldA, SomefieldB, Null As SomefieldC, Null As SomefieldD
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT NameB, [ID-B], Null As SomefieldA, Null As SomefieldB, SomefieldC, SomefieldD
FROM TableB
```

If you want to perform a left join on the result, you would have to use a subquery, and it would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (    
    SELECT NameA, [ID-A] As ID, SomefieldA, SomefieldB, Null As SomefieldC, Null As SomefieldD
    FROM TableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NameB, [ID-B], Null As SomefieldA, Null As SomefieldB, SomefieldC, SomefieldD
    FROM TableB
) AS UQuery
LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableC.ID = UQuery.ID
```

Comment: Thanks! if I want to then perform a left outer join on this union, how would that look? I'd be joining with a third table based on the name.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing merging here. Well, this should do:

```
select name, id, field_a, field_b, null as field_c, null as field_d from a
union all
select name, id, null as field_a, null as field_b, field_c, field_d from b;
```